# What is the difference between binding redirection under packagereference and packages.config?

Tags: .net, packagereference, packages.config

On multiple GitHub issues, you can see that there are differences between packages.config and Package Reference.
Most explanations: packages.config is bound during download and Package Reference is at runtime, but what are the specific differences? Is the bound package version different? Which package is different? Or something else? Thank you very much for your help